# Updating part of a Document in Azure DocumentDB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, nosql

Is there a way to update part of a document in a DocumentDB collection?

I know that `ReplaceDocumentAsync` lets you update a document, but you have to replace the *entire* document. This sounds kind of scary. If I have an object that has other objects nested I will have to query for the parent document and then replace the entire document to update a nested part of the object.

Does DocumentDB handle `ReplaceDocumentAsync` in a way that makes it perform better than it might seem on the surface?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately, as of now, this is not possible. You can vote up the suggestion on the Microsoft Azure User Voice page.

http://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-documentdb/suggestions/6693091-be-able-to-do-partial-updates-on-document

## More Information

Scott Guthrie's Blog: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/azure-new-documentdb-nosql-service-new-search-service-new-sql-alwayson-vm-template-and-more

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/822d4b5c-13ce-4737-a1e9-6217851dfa9c/update-delete-parts-of-an-documentdb-object-graph-how-do-weak-relations-work?forum=AzureDocumentDB

Here is a comment from a Microsoft employee, stating that support for partial document updates will be added in a future update:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/documentdb/archive/2014/08/22/introducing-azure-documentdb-microsoft-s-fully-managed-nosql-document-database-service.aspx
[image: Blog Comment]

Comment: **_Still not available as of April 2017._**

Comment: The user voice feature request has been updated on Mar 5, 2018: 
***Azure Cosmos DB Team (Admin, Microsoft Azure) responded: We are actively working on this feature.*** .- Hurray