# How to update a subdocument array column in azure documentdb via a posttrigger?

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-cosmosdb

How to update a subdocument array column in documentdb via a posttrigger (JS)? specifically, how to increment the 2nd option votecount

```
   {
        "name": "Question 1",
        "options": [
            {
                "Option": "option 1",
                "id": "1",
                "votecount": 0
            },
            {
                "Option": "option 2",
                "id": "2",
                "votecount": 0
            },
            {
                "Option": "option 3",
                "id": "3",
                "votecount": 0
            }
        ]
}
```

Comment: I know documentdb does not support partial updates, I just need to  increment the votecount value before replacing the entire document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is how to increment the property before attempting to update the document:

document.options[createdDoc.index].votecount++;

Answer (score 0):

I tried to find ways to update parts of documents in azure cosmos db but failed .

[It](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29136834/updating-part-of-a-document-in-azure-documentdb) seems that azure cosmos db doesn't support `partial updates` now. You could update entire document in `stored procedure`.

Sample code as below for reference:

```
function updateSproc(id, update) {
    var collection = getContext().getCollection();
    var collectionLink = collection.getSelfLink();
    var response = getContext().getResponse();

    tryQueryAndUpdate();

    function tryQueryAndUpdate(continuation) {
        var query = {query: "select * from root r where r.id = @id", parameters: [{name: "@id", value: id}]};
        var requestOptions = {continuation: continuation};

        var isAccepted = collection.queryDocuments(collectionLink, query, requestOptions, function (err, documents, responseOptions) {
            if (err) throw err;

            if (documents.length > 0) {
                tryUpdate(documents[0]);
            } else {
                throw new Error("Document not found.");
            }
        });
    }

function tryUpdate(document) {
    var requestOptions = {etag: document._etag};

    var fields, i;

    fields = Object.keys(update);
    for (i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
       document[fields[i]] = update[fields[i]];
    }

    var isAccepted = collection.replaceDocument(document._self, document, requestOptions, function (err, updatedDocument, responseOptions) {
        if (err) throw err;
        response.setBody(updatedDocument);
    });
}
```

However, Azure Cosmos DB support `MongoDB protocol`. You could confirm it on [Azure official page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-introduction).

So,`incremental operations` are supported. Please refer to this [link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/).

Hope it helps you.Any concern,please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Thanks Jay, I'm not using mongodb driver, all I wanted to do is to access the votecount field which I managed to do via the following: document.Answers[docToCreate.optionId-1].votecount++; (I was doing the same from the beginning but the error was somewhere else)

Comment: I was referring to the request object while I should have used the response object, response object is available in post-triggers while request object are available for pre-triggers