# How to deal with references in azure cosmos db

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-cosmosdb

First of all I'm new to CosmosDB (NoSQL) and have only worked with SQL-Server so far. I want to migrate to CosmosDB and have a hard time understanding some basic concepts. I understand that everything is a document and there are no joins, everything is denormalized and so on.

Let's say I want to create a model for some sports league. I have teams, teams have players, and the teams are in a league.

```
{
"typename": "League",
"id": "league.1",
"teams": [
    {
        "typename": "Team",
        "id": "team.1",
        "leagueId": "league.1",
        "players": [
            {
                "typename": "Player",
                "id": "Player.1",
                "teamId": "team.1",
                "name": "John"
            },
            {
                "typename": "Player",
                "id": "Player.1",
                "teamId": "team.1",
                "name": "Alex"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

The players and teams don't change very often so (I think) it would be fine to store them in a league document. If I would query for a specific league I would get all teams and all players. What if I would query for a specific team? Or what if I want to get the team a specific player is in? Do I have to create documents for every team / player?

What if I would create a new player document? From my actual understanding I would have to update the team that contains the player and even the league. Is this the right approach? This somehow doesn't seem natural to me. If so, how would I do this? I tried stored procedures or triggers. Both are fairly hard to implement (my opinion) as I have no tools to test and debug. The triggers also would be executed recursive (create player leads to updating the team, which leads to updating the league).

If this is the way to go, what is best practice here? Stored procedures? Triggers? Are there any tools to make the development more productive?

I also tried referencing the teams in the league by their id. This makes updating the teams really easy. The downside is that I would have several calls to get all teams of a given league resulting in higher read times.

Can someone get me on the right track?

Comment: Unfortunately, schema-design is a fairly broad topic, and there's no way to give you a single, objective answer. And schema has nothing to do with triggers and stored procedures. A document database doesn't preclude you from referencing other documents. There are no rules that say you must embed, vs reference, other documents.

Answer (score 0):

> What if I would query for a specific team? Or what if I want to get
>   the team a specific player is in? Do I have to create documents for
>   every team / player?

No, you don't have to create documents for every team or player. `Azure cosmos DB(NoSQL)` is `Document` type Database. So it is `schema-less` and can be `nested`.

My suggestion is you could create per document for per league.I thought this design pattern is the most intuitive and best suited to your needs.

I tried to create sample `league` document:

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "basketball",
    "team": [
        {
            "teamId": "11",
            "name": "team1",
            "player": [
                {
                    "playerId": "11A",
                    "playerName": "A"
                },
                {
                    "playerId": "11B",
                    "playerName": "B"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "teamId": "22",
            "name": "team2",
            "player": [
                {
                    "playerId": "22C",
                    "playerName": "C"
                },
                {
                    "playerId": "22D",
                    "playerName": "D"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

> What if I would create a new player document? From my actual
>   understanding I would have to update the team that contains the player
>   and even the league.

It seems you want update parts of documents not entire.Per my experience, azure cosmos db [doesn't support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29136834/updating-part-of-a-document-in-azure-documentdb) partial updates now.

However, Azure Cosmos DB support `MongoDB protocol`. You could confirm it on [Azure official page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-introduction).

Please refer to this [link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/).

> I tried stored procedures or triggers. Both are fairly hard to
>   implement (my opinion) as I have no tools to test and debug.

Both `Stored Procedure` and `Triggers` are all `JavaScript` running on the azure cosmos db server side.So, you can't directly test and debug it.

However,`Azure Cosmos DB SDK` provides a `getScriptLog` method to get the `console. Log ()` statement. So, you could add `console.log()` to debug your JS code.

I'm not sure which language you're using in the backend.

Please refer to this thread which I replied for more details:[Microsoft Azure CosmostDB Script Explorer console.log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45742082/microsoft-azure-cosmostdb-script-explorer-console-log/45751265#45751265).

Hope it helps you.If any concern , please feel free to let me know.

Comment: There's really no right answer to this. The organization of the OP's data is going to be dependent on their app and how they query it.  You're proposing a single `League` document, with every team and every player, making it difficult (or costly) to manipulate, say, a single player. And you're introducing arrays of arrays (again, complicating queries).

Comment: My understanding was that CosmosDB provides fast reads at the cost of slow updates (or creates), which is totally fine for me. My expectation is that the api requests are 95% read and 5% write. @Jay thank you for your suggestion in using MongoDB. I will give it a try.

Comment: @user3838018 OK! you could also notice that debug your SP or Trigger by using console.log().

Comment: @user3838018 Hi, is mongoDB api in document DB feasible?